# Why Xorg server fails on system created with Buildroot for Raspberry Pi4?

Tags: opengl-es, raspberry-pi4, buildroot, xorg

I am trying to create my own system for Raspberry Pi4 using Buildroot.
Target is to make custom OS with Xorg, Qt5 and OpenGLESv2 HW rendering. I create my custom Buildroot configuration, nothing specific yet. Very similar to default raspberry pi4 buildroot config but enabled Xorg/Mesa/OpenGLES. My config is that:

```
BR2_arm=y
BR2_cortex_a72=y
BR2_ARM_FPU_NEON_VFPV4=y
BR2_CCACHE=y
BR2_CCACHE_DIR="$(BR2_EXTERNAL_I_TREE_PATH)/../.buildroot-ccache"
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_GLIBC=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_CXX=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_HOSTNAME="MyHost"
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_ISSUE="Welcome to MyHost"
BR2_ROOTFS_DEVICE_CREATION_DYNAMIC_EUDEV=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_ROOT_PASSWD="4rt56gbd"
BR2_SYSTEM_DHCP="eth0"
BR2_ROOTFS_USERS_TABLES="$(BR2_EXTERNAL_I_TREE_PATH)/board/rpi4/users.txt"
BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY="$(BR2_EXTERNAL_I_TREE_PATH)/rootfs_overlay/"
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_BUILD_SCRIPT="$(BR2_EXTERNAL_I_TREE_PATH)/board/rpi4/post-build.sh"
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_IMAGE_SCRIPT="$(BR2_EXTERNAL_I_TREE_PATH)/board/rpi4/post-image.sh"
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_SCRIPT_ARGS="--add-miniuart-bt-overlay"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_TARBALL=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_TARBALL_LOCATION="$(call github,raspberrypi,linux,967d45b29ca2902f031b867809d72e3b3d623e7a)/linux-967d45b29ca2902f031b867809d72e3b3d623e7a.tar.gz"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG="bcm2711"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_DTS_SUPPORT=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_INTREE_DTS_NAME="bcm2711-rpi-4-b"
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_NEEDS_HOST_OPENSSL=y
BR2_PACKAGE_GLMARK2=y
BR2_PACKAGE_MESA3D_DEMOS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_MESA3D=y
BR2_PACKAGE_MESA3D_GALLIUM_DRIVER_KMSRO=y
BR2_PACKAGE_MESA3D_GALLIUM_DRIVER_V3D=y
BR2_PACKAGE_MESA3D_GALLIUM_DRIVER_VC4=y
BR2_PACKAGE_MESA3D_OPENGL_GLX=y
BR2_PACKAGE_MESA3D_OPENGL_ES=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XORG7=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XSERVER_XORG_SERVER=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XCB_UTIL_CURSOR=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XCB_UTIL_KEYSYMS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XCB_UTIL_WM=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XLIB_LIBFS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XLIB_LIBXSCRNSAVER=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XLIB_LIBXCOMPOSITE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XLIB_LIBXFONT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XLIB_LIBXTST=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XLIB_LIBXVMC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XLIB_LIBXXF86DGA=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XLIB_LIBDMX=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XAPP_X11PERF=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XAPP_XCALC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XAPP_XCLOCK=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_INPUT_KEYBOARD=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_INPUT_LIBINPUT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_INPUT_MOUSE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_FBDEV=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_FBTURBO=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_ADOBE_100DPI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_ADOBE_75DPI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_ADOBE_UTOPIA_100DPI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_ADOBE_UTOPIA_75DPI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_ADOBE_UTOPIA_TYPE1=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_ARABIC_MISC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_BH_100DPI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_BH_75DPI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_BH_LUCIDATYPEWRITER_100DPI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_BH_LUCIDATYPEWRITER_75DPI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_BH_TTF=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_BH_TYPE1=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_BITSTREAM_100DPI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_BITSTREAM_75DPI=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_BITSTREAM_TYPE1=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_CRONYX_CYRILLIC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_DAEWOO_MISC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_DEC_MISC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_IBM_TYPE1=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_ISAS_MISC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_JIS_MISC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_MICRO_MISC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_MISC_CYRILLIC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_MISC_ETHIOPIC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_MISC_MELTHO=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_MUTT_MISC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_SCHUMACHER_MISC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_SCREEN_CYRILLIC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_SONY_MISC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_SUN_MISC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_WINITZKI_CYRILLIC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XFONT_FONT_XFREE86_TYPE1=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XDATA_XCURSOR_THEMES=y
BR2_PACKAGE_NODM=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XTERM=y
BR2_PACKAGE_OPENBOX=y
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_FIRMWARE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_FIRMWARE_VARIANT_PI4=y
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_FIRMWARE_X=y
BR2_PACKAGE_PYTHON3=y
BR2_PACKAGE_LIBDRI2=y
BR2_PACKAGE_OPENSSH=y
BR2_PACKAGE_SUDO=y
BR2_PACKAGE_S6=y
BR2_PACKAGE_S6_LINUX_UTILS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_S6_PORTABLE_UTILS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_UTIL_LINUX_BINARIES=y
BR2_PACKAGE_UTIL_LINUX_KILL=y
BR2_PACKAGE_UTIL_LINUX_MOUNT=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_4=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE="512M"
# BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_TAR is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_DOSFSTOOLS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_GENIMAGE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_MTOOLS=y
```

First issue comes with X server.
It starts working but very strange/ubnormal. Xorg logs show me lines:

```
(II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
(II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
(II) no primary bus or device found falling back to sys/devices/platform/gpu/drm/card1
```

But on normal Raspbian OS X server first adds card0 then card1. And makes fall back to card0. Why my Xorg starts with card1?
I think this is my main issue, because of that later GLX extension does not start. And so I cannot make OpenGLES working in my system.

In my config.txt i have line
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

and I belive vc4 drivers start properly because I see /dev/dri/card0 /dev/dri/card1 and /dev/dri/renderD128 devices

Maybe someone had similar experience?
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My fault in question.
I was wrong that issue was in order of /dev/dri/card? adding by Xorg.
Issue was different. xserver built in buildroot needs libglamor enabled? this should be enabled in buildroot config. If enabled then es2_info reports no issue with OpenGLES.. besides that in my case still glmark2-es2 does not work with error "Failed to open bo 1: Permission denied"